# Is there an AngularJS way to use a browser modal with a promise return?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code uses a custom modal here:

```
var modalInstance = this.$modal.open({
   templateUrl: '/app/tests/partials/markTest.html',
   controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'testService', ($scope,  $modalInstance, testService: ITestService) => {
   $scope.cancel = () => {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
   };
   $scope.ok = () => {
      testService.markTest()
         .then(() => {
            abc().then(() => {
               $modalInstance.close();
            })
         });
   $scope.tes = testService;
   }]
});
```

I would really like to use the browser's built in modal similar to that which shows up on stackoverflow when I try to leave a page that I am editing.

Is this even possible in my case as I need to be able to do an action after a user clicks okay and only then if that action works would I close the modal.

Any tips and advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no. The Window alert/confirm dialogs are blocking so can't work with a promise.

You would need an HTML/custom javascript solution to work with a promise, like the Angular dialog.

The only real advantage of Window.alert() is that it is blocking, so if you don't want to block why use it?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the Angular Dialog? Right now I am using something that I think came from Bootstrap AngularJS.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the most popular one the bootstrap modal. But there are others around too (ngDialog for example).  If you google for "angular modal popup" or "angular modal dialog" I'm sure there are others. Or you can roll your own fairly easily. It's just a fixed position div over the rest of the content..